# Learning Functions [Error: undefined columns selected]

Tags: r, function

R newbie here.

I'm learning functions, and i have a problem running this:

```
newfunction = function(x) {
    limit = ncol(x)
    for(i in 1:limit){
       if(anyNA(x[,i] == T)) {
            x[,i] = NULL
       }
    } 
}

newfunction(WBD_SA)
```

I get the error: `Error in '[.data.frame(x, , i) : undefined columns selected`

I'm trying to remove all columns that have any NA values from my data set WBD_SA.

I know `na.omit()` removes for **rows** with NA values, but not sure if there is something for **columns**.

Any suggestions regarding packages/functions that can make this happen are also appreciated.

Cheers!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are getting this error because you are iterating from `1` to `limit`, where `limit` is the number of columns at the **start** of the function, and you're dropping columns from the data.frame as you iterate through the `for` loop.  This means that if you drop even 1 column, `ncol(x)` will be less than `limit` by the time the for loop ends.  I'll give you 3 alternatives that work:

1. iterate backward:

   ```
   for(i in limit:1)
      if(anyNA(x[,i] == TRUE)) 
           x[,i] = NULL
   ```

   with the above loop, the `i`'th column will always be in the the same position as the it was when the `for` loop started.
2. iterate forward using a `while` loop:

   ```
   i = 1
   while(i <=ncol(x)){
      if(anyNA(x[,i] == TRUE))
           x[,i] = NULL
      i=i+1
   }
   ```
3. use the fact that data.frames are subclasses of lists, and use lapply to create an index that is `TRUE` for columns that contain a missing value and `FALSE` otherwise, like so:

   ```
   columnHasMissingValue <- lapply(x,function(y)any(is.na(y))) 
   x  <-  x[,!columnHasMissingValue]
   ```

   as long as you're learing about data.frames, it's useful that you can use negative indicies to drop column like so:

   ```
   x  <-  x[,-which(columnHasMissingValue)]
   ```

   Note that the above solution is similar to the `apply` solution in user1362215's solution, which takes advantage of the fact that data.frames have two dimensions* so you can apply a function over the second margin (columns) like so:

   ```
   good_cols = apply(x,# the object over which to apply the function
                     2,# apply the function over the second margin (columns)
                     function(x) # the function to apply
                         !any(is.na(x))
                     )
   x = x[,good_cols]
   ```

* 2 dimensions means that the `[` operator defined for the data.frame class takes 2 arguments that are interpreted as rows and columns indexes.

Comment: May I humbly suggest to replace `== T` by `== TRUE`?

Comment: Absolutely.  @Pascal is pointing out that `T` is an ordinary variable that can be redefined at run time (e.g. `T <- FALSE`) whereas `TRUE` is a reserved word that cannot be re-defined, and is hence the safer way to evaluate a value...

Comment: That answered my question more than i had ever hoped it would. Thank you so much! I'm still not too familiar to `lapply()` and `apply()` , but i'm getting there. Thanks again to everyone who contributed.

Answer (score 0):

When you are iterating over the columns, using `x[,i] = NULL` removes the column, reducing the number of columns by 1.  Unless `i` is the last column, this will produce errors for future values of `i`.  You should instead do something like this

```
good_cols = apply(x,2,function(x) {!any(is.na(x))})
x = x[,good_cols]
```

`apply(x,margin,function)` applies `function` over the `margin` dimension (rows for the value of 1, columns for the value of 2; 3 or higher is possible with arrays) of `x`, which is more efficient than looping (and doesn't cause errors from changing `x` partway).